# Openlayers 3 Coords

Tags: javascript, php, yii2, openlayers-3

I'm newbee of OL. I need just to put some point on the map and ideally make some request for writting info about this point to db, but now i just want to alert(coords) of point. So, i found an example, where i can put some point, line and polygone to the map.

```js
var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
  });

  var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [raster],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
      center: [-11000000, 4600000],
      zoom: 4
    })
  });

  var features = new ol.Collection();
  var featureOverlay = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({features: features}),
    style: new ol.style.Style({
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
      }),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: '#ffcc33',
        width: 2
      }),
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 7,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: '#ffcc33'
        })
      })
    })
  });
  featureOverlay.setMap(map);

  var modify = new ol.interaction.Modify({
    features: features,
    // the SHIFT key must be pressed to delete vertices, so
    // that new vertices can be drawn at the same position
    // of existing vertices
    deleteCondition: function(event) {
      //var feature = event.element;
      //var coord = event.feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
      //coord = ol.proj.transform(coord, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
      //  alert(coord);
      return ol.events.condition.shiftKeyOnly(event) &&
          ol.events.condition.singleClick(event);
    }
  });
  map.addInteraction(modify);

  var draw; // global so we can remove it later
  var typeSelect = document.getElementById('type');

  function addInteraction() {

    draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
      features: features,
      type: /** @type {ol.geom.GeometryType} */ (typeSelect.value)
    /*draw.on('drawend', function (event) {
      // get the feature
      var feature = event.element;
      var coord = event.feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
      alert(coord);*/
    });


    map.addInteraction(draw);
  }


  /**
   * Handle change event.
   */
  typeSelect.onchange = function() {
    map.removeInteraction(draw);
    addInteraction();
  };

  addInteraction();
// Code of adding to DB our features

  //
```

```html
<?php
/* @var $this yii\web\View */
use yii\helpers\Html;
use sibilino\yii2\openlayers\ol;
use sibilino\yii2\openlayers\OpenLayers;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Draw and Modify Features</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.18.2/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
  <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
  <script src="http://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
  <script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.18.2/build/ol.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<form class="form-inline">
  <label>Geometry type &nbsp;</label>
  <select id="type">
    <option value="Point">Point</option>
    <option value="LineString">LineString</option>
    <option value="Polygon">Polygon</option>
  </select>
</form>
<script>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It works normally with all libs, and I can put points, lines and polygones to the map, but I can't get coord of the points, which I put. I tried to create some listener, it's commented in this code, looks like

```
//var feature = event.element;
  //var coord = event.feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
  //coord = ol.proj.transform(coord, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
  //  alert(coord);
```

But this method as I understood listens mouse moving too, and I'm getting some errors like:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getGeometry' of undefined
```

If somebody have time to read this long question, what can I do, and how to do right for getting my coords and saving this to  DB?

Comment: Try `feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates()` instead of `event.feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates()`.

Comment: do you know how to load this points to the map, or i need to make a new question? =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to redact this code:

```
function addInteraction() {

draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
  features: features,
  type: /** @type {ol.geom.GeometryType} */ (typeSelect.value)
/*draw.on('drawend', function (event) {
  // get the feature
  var feature = event.element;
  var coord = event.feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
  alert(coord);*/
});


map.addInteraction(draw);
```

}

To:

```
function addInteraction() {

draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
  features: features,
  type: /** @type {ol.geom.GeometryType} */ (typeSelect.value)

});

// Code of adding to DB our features

draw.on('drawend', function (event) {
  var feature = event.element;
  var coord = event.feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
 alert(coord);

  var title=document.getElementById('type');

   var url = "http://localhost/basic/web/index.php?r=sggis/create&title="+title.value+"&point="+coord;
   function lol(){
     var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhr.open("GET", url, false);
     xhr.send();
   }
  lol();
});
```

And in yii2 Controller i have written an action which just gets title and coords just from the request. It's unsafe, but then I'll redact this one.
At all, every point, line or poly which i put on the map saves their coords to postgresSQL's DataBase.